# Python widgets and button

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm trying to add a "Done" button to my program that will print the content of both Entry widgets to a new box.  I can get the button to appear, but I can't get the information to show up in a new box.  What am I doing wrong?

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self._name = StringVar()
        self._name.set("Enter name here")
        self._age = IntVar()
        self._age.set("Enter age here")
        top = self.winfo_toplevel()         # find top-level window
        top.title("Entry Example")

        self._createWidgets()

        self._button = Button(self,
                          text = "Done")
        self._button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

    def _createWidgets(self):
        textEntry = Entry(self, takefocus=1,
                          textvariable = self._name, width = 40)
        textEntry.grid(row=0, sticky=E+W)

        ageEntry = Entry(self, takefocus=1, 
                         textvariable = self._age, width = 20)
        ageEntry.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

    def _widget(self):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo



# end class Application

def main():
Application().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an action to your button using `command:` option.

To get what is written in `Entry` you need to use `get()` method.

`showinfo` you need two arguments, one is the title, the other one is what is going to be shown.

Also you need to `import tkMessageBox`.

Here is a working example.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.txt = tk.Entry(root)
        self.age = tk.Entry(root)
        self.btn = tk.Button(root, text="Done", command=self.message)

        self.txt.pack()
        self.age.pack()
        self.btn.pack()

    def message(self):
        ent1 = self.txt.get()
        ent2 = self.age.get()
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Title","Name: %s \nAge: %s" %(ent1,ent2))



if __name__=="__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Example")
    example = Example(root)
    example.mainloop()
```